# Count string occurances in all sheets in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office, cell, countif

I need to count all occurances of a specified string in all sheets of an excel file. I thought I'll use COUNTIF, but it can't handle 3D cell references. There is an other function I could use? I want to avoid VBA. If there is no simpler way, I'll use python.

Comment: Any reason you can't use one COUNTIF per sheet then sum them up?

Comment: without vba, use python. the only alternative is an over-complicated volatile array formula.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I've tried, but didn't worked. The solution here [link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/115624-count-instances-of-a-string-in-an-excel-workbook-not-just-a-sheet) gave me only a big whole 0. I know I missed something, but not clear what.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks, I'll try the Python way then. VBA makes me shiver... :D